# Facebook Graph API: Explain permissions to user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

Is it possible to ask for the wanted permissions and displaying some individual text in the permissions-dialogue that's showed to the user? E.g. "We use the permission to read your mail address to create a new account in our community."?

Thanks,
indect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier the [Login Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/) would have the option to display the app description that developers could use to inform the Users about the need for the specific permissions. Which looked like following and was described in this [blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/633/)

[image: Old Login Dialog]

But the Login Dialog has then seen few modifications, as outlined by this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/12/providing-people-greater-clarity-and-control/) for grater clarity and control due to which the Login Dialog has changed to its current form which has no option for the developers to inform Users about the request. If you want to inform about it, do it prior to sending the User to authorization, as the new Login Dialog looks like

[image: New Login Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

No, these messages are default by the facebook.